# how can we change gravatar image in wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, gravatar

**Hi all,**

I was wondering if there is a way in which we can put our own photos in wordpress gravatar without signing up to "http://en.gravatar.com/".

I am making a profile-management-system in wordpress. I am almost there but just an issue that I cannot show that display picture in comments as an avatar.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't. You have to pass through http://gravatar.com

Comment: Thanks but I think there must be a way.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look into this plugin: http://wordpress.org/plugins/user-avatar/

Comment: Fair to say the accepted "correct answer" isn't actually the correct one?